# How to show $e^t$ is the unique solution to the integral equation $\int_0^1 e^{ts} x(s) ds = \frac{e^{t+1}-1}{t+1}$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to show $x(t) = e^t$ is the unique solution to the following integral equation? $$\int_0^1 e^{ts} x(s) ds = \frac{e^{t+1}-1}{t+1}$$

My thoughts:
$$(t+1)\int_0^1 e^{ts} x(s) ds = e^{t+1}-1 $$
Integrating by parts gives:

$$\int_0^1 e^{ts}(x(s)-x'(s)) ds = (e - x(1))e^{t} + x(0) - 1$$

Taking the $k$-th derivative of both sides about $t$:

$$\int_0^1 s^k e^{ts}(x(s)-x'(s)) ds = (e - x(1))e^{t}$$

Let $t = 0$

$$\int_0^1 s^k (x(s)-x'(s)) ds = e - x(1)$$

I cannot figure out how to proceed next.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $x(s)$ and $y(s)$ both satisfy the integral equation. Then  $\int_0^1 e^{ts}(x(s)-y(s))ds=0$ for all $t$. Then the same is true if we replace $e^{ts}$ with a finite linear combination of elements of the family
 $\left\{e^{ts}\right\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$. Thus 
$$\int_0^1 f(s)(x(s)-y(s))ds,\qquad \forall f\in \operatorname{span}\left\{e^{ts}\right\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}} $$ 
But $\operatorname{span}\left\{e^{ts}\right\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is a subalgebra of $C([0,1])$ which separates points and contains a nonzero constant function (let $t=0$), and therefore by the [Stone-Weierstrass theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stone%E2%80%93Weierstrass_theorem), it is dense in $C([0,1])$. Thus, using a standard limiting under the integral sign procedure,
$$\int_0^1 f(s)(x(s)-y(s))ds=0,\qquad \forall f\in C([0,1]) $$
It is now a [known fact in analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_lemma_of_calculus_of_variations) that this implies $x(s)-y(s)\equiv 0$, i.e. $x=y$. Thus the solution to your integral equation is unique.

Comment: I don't understand "$\{e^{ts}\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is a subalgebra of $C([0,1])$ which separates points and contains a nonzero constant function".  This set is not polynomial function set ?

Comment: The basic version of the Stone-Weierstrass theorem says that polynomials are dense in $C([0,1])$. There are many generalizations and one of them says that "if $X$ is a compact Hausdorff space and $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X;\mathbb{R})$ which contains a non-zero constant function, then $A$ is dense in $C(X;\mathbb{R})$ if and only if it separates points" (quoting from the wikipedia page I linked in the answer). Anyway, $\left\{e^{ts}\right\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is not a subalgebra, its generated vector subspace $\operatorname{span}\left\{e^{ts}\right\}_{t\in \mathbb{R}}$ is.